# Pair magic keyboard with iPad

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth

I cannot pair my new Magic keyboard with my iPad. It shows up in the Bluetooth devices list as "Bluetooth Keyboard", but when I click to connect it I get the message:

> **Connection Unsuccessful**
>  Make sure "Bluetooth Keyboard" is turned on and in range.

How can I pair the devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the Genius Bar to solve this. They did the standard procedure and the device paired.

The explanation for why it was not working for me was that **a Magic Keyboard will not pair while it is charging**. I had the keyboard plugged into a USB port for charging at the time. To use or pair the keyboard, make sure it is unplugged.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  You can't "swap out batteries" b/c it doesn't have any. Once I paired the keyboard to my computer, it would not re-pair to my iPad...even if I "forget" the keyboard from my computer.  Very frustrating that there is no way to force the keyboard into pairing mode.

Solution was to tell the iPad to "Forget" the keyboard too. Then it was able to re-pair.

Answer (score 0):

For people with the older Apple Bluetooth Keyboard:

Make sure that when you've pressed the power button on the side of the keyboard that the green light turns on that is on the top of the keyboard. If it doesn't, maybe try swapping out the batteries.

This answer doesn't apply with the newer Magic Keyboard with rechargeable batteries; for that one, see the other answers.